# file contains no section headers

Tags: linux, git, hadoop

i am new to linux and i am trying to install hadoop on VM with cent-os , while following the instructions from " hadoop for dummies" all worked but ...
when i run yum ..this is what happens:

```
ot@localhost ~]# yum install hadoop\* mahout\* oozie\* hbase\* hive\* hue\* pig\* zookeeper\*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security

File contains no section headers.
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo, line: 1
'--2015-02-28 07:06:49--  http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-0.7.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo\n'
```

please help me to get this fixed, i did find few answers regarding the same issue but it did not help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `file://///etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo` has some syntax errors. Go in and edit the file, and fix the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your repo is right and avilible, it has defined rule to write it.Examples:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch 
failovermethod=priority 
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Answer (score 0):

you will face this error if you have any syntax errors in repos file. Please check your repo file present in **/etc/yum.repos.d/**